# How to Set same height for all the textfield of a row of an item in list view builder. and the height should be the maximum amongst all textfield

Tags: flutter, dart

I was building an application which records list of large data. and i am using textfields for the same. the height of the textfield should be dynamic, so i set maxLine to null. and i want one more feature is that when a textfield height grows as adding data to it,i want to set the same height for the rest of the textfields in the row. i tried with Intrinsic height , which fails to grow textfield height as typing into it.

im adding all the code im written below.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ListTest extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListTest({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ListTest> createState() => _ListTestState();
}

class _ListTestState extends State<ListTest> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 30),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            const Text("Welcome"),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                itemCount: 10,
                itemBuilder: (c, i) {
                  return IntrinsicHeight(
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        const SizedBox(
                          width: 30,
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: TextField(
                            maxLines: null,
                            decoration: decoration,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: TextField(
                            maxLines: null,
                            decoration: decoration,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: TextField(
                            maxLines: null,
                            decoration: decoration,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: TextField(
                            maxLines: null,
                            decoration: decoration,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: TextField(
                            maxLines: null,
                            decoration: decoration,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  final decoration = InputDecoration(
    border: border,
    focusedBorder: border,
    enabledBorder: border,
  );
  static final border = OutlineInputBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
    borderSide: const BorderSide(
      color: Colors.grey,
    )
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want that if i write text in one textfield and if it expands, then all the textfields in that row should expand.
For that, one simple solution is to add
**`expands:true`**
to every textfield widget in the code as shown below.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const ListTest(),
    );
  }
}



class ListTest extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListTest({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ListTest> createState() => _ListTestState();
}

class _ListTestState extends State<ListTest> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 30),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            const Text("Welcome"),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                itemCount: 10,
                itemBuilder: (c, i) {
                  return IntrinsicHeight(
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        const SizedBox(
                          width: 30,
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: TextField(
                            maxLines: null,
                            expands:true,
                            decoration: decoration,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: TextField(
                            maxLines: null,
                            expands:true,
                            decoration: decoration,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: TextField(
                            maxLines: null,
                            expands:true,
                            decoration: decoration,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: TextField(
                            maxLines: null,
                            expands:true,
                            decoration: decoration,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: TextField(
                            maxLines: null,
                            expands:true,
                            decoration: decoration,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  final decoration = InputDecoration(
    border: border,
    focusedBorder: border,
    enabledBorder: border,
  );
  static final border = OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      borderSide: const BorderSide(
        color: Colors.grey,
      ));
}
```

[Solution Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNyHT.jpg)